# jaxb circular dependency maven compile error

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I've code which generates classes and these are referenced in main package
I'm using jaxb2 plugin and running on commandline. my code creates generate-sources ,but compile fails saying symbol can't find.
can somebody help me what's going wrong. here is my plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
<configuration>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <schemaInclude>*-1.0.xsd</schemaInclude>
            </schemaIncludes>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <bindingInclude>*bindings-1.0.xjb</bindingInclude>
            </bindingIncludes>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Please post your error codes.

Comment: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getPlans()
[ERROR] location: variable xmlType of type com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.descriptor.XMLDeploymentDescriptorType    ----  XmlDeplymentDescriptorType is the generated class and I can see this under  generate-sources/xjc/com  etc.,